# Buckminster headless build utf-8 encoding

Tags: encoding, jenkins, eclipse-rcp, headless, buckminster

We have an Jenkins CI, which creates our Eclipse RCP application. It was set up with this tutorial: http://www.ralfebert.de/blog/eclipsercp/rcp_builds/ . So far so good, we didn´t have any problems until we decided to use utf-8 encoding for our project instead of the default cp1252 encoding. So the problem is if we start the created application that the encoding is damaged. I tried everything especially with jvm -dfile.encoding="utf-8" arguments. I tried this in rcp.target, jenkins arguments and build.xml build properties.

Have someone any idea how i can fix my problem?

thanks for every response

Answer (score 1):

We have the same issue as well, unfortunately unsolved so far. I think the charset must be set in time of compilation. So this may be a jvm argument instead of program argument.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have saved the encoding information in the project. If there is no such information, the eclipse instance default encoding will be used, which in turns defaults to the platform's default encoding.

Buckminster build uses the eclipse build which honors the resource meta data.

An anti pattern is to change the default in Eclipse, and not save it in projects. The next user with a different default then risks creating a complete mess, especially if they also change the default and save.

Comment: my default encoding in eclipse is utf-8 if i export my eclipse application with the eclipse export wizard, everything is fine. where else can i set the encoding? in .project file?? plugin.properties of my eclipse application?

Comment: @holzleube The encoding is saved in `${project}/.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs`. Mine has a line with `encoding/<project>=UTF-8`.